# How is the definition of differentiability of a function from a subset of a regular surface is equivalent to the usual definition?

Tags: differential-geometry

Recently, I am reading Do Carmo Differential Geometry Book. While solving exercises problems, I came across this puzzling question.

[image]

**as usual**

I am clear that if f is such restriction, then f is differentiable(as defined in terms of regular surface). But, I am not able to prove that if f is differentiable in the regular surface sense, then how it is differentiable in as function from an open subset of **R**^3.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: **HINT**: By the implicit function theorem, each point of a regular surface has a coordinate neighborhood in $\Bbb R^3$ in which the surface appears as $x_3=0$.